# PL SQL alternative to nested exceptions

Tags: sql, oracle, exception, plsql, where-clause

**I wanna know if there is any alternative to solve this kind of logic, without use nested exception. This is part of a Function that returns an integer value. Thanks.**

```
IF PNOMTARIFA = 'DEPOSITO' 
THEN
   BEGIN
      SELECT CL.ID_TIPO_CONT_LINEA, 
             CL.NOMBRE_TIPO_CONTENEDOR, 
             TC.DEPOSITO ,
             L.NOMBRE
        INTO idcontlinea, 
             tcontenedor, 
             deposito, 
             vlinea
        FROM TIPO_CONT TE, 
             TIPO_CONT_LINEA CL, 
             TARIFAS_DEPOSITO TC, 
             LINEAS L
       WHERE TE.ID_TIPO_CONT = CL.ID_TIPO_CONTENEDOR
         AND CL.ID_TIPO_CONT_LINEA = TC.ID_TIPO_CONT_LINEA
         AND CL.LINEA = L.LINEA
         AND TE.ID_TIPO_CONT = PTIPO_CONT
         AND CL.LINEA = PLINEA
         AND TC.NIT = PNITCLIENTE
         AND TC.BL = PNUMBL
         AND TC.VIGENCIA_DEPOSITO >= trunc(SYSDATE);

    EXCEPTION 
       WHEN OTHERS THEN 
         BEGIN
            SELECT CL.ID_TIPO_CONT_LINEA, 
                   CL.NOMBRE_TIPO_CONTENEDOR, 
                   TC.DEPOSITO ,
                   L.NOMBRE
              INTO idcontlinea, 
                   tcontenedor, 
                   deposito, 
                   vlinea
              FROM TIPO_CONT TE, 
                   TIPO_CONT_LINEA CL, 
                   TARIFAS_DEPOSITO TC, 
                   LINEAS L
             WHERE TE.ID_TIPO_CONT = CL.ID_TIPO_CONTENEDOR
               AND CL.ID_TIPO_CONT_LINEA = TC.ID_TIPO_CONT_LINEA
               AND CL.LINEA = L.LINEA
               AND TE.ID_TIPO_CONT = PTIPO_CONT
               AND CL.LINEA = PLINEA
               AND TC.NIT = PNITCLIENTE
               AND TC.PUERTO_CARGUE = PPTOCARGUE
               AND TC.PUERTO_DESCARGUE = PPTODESCARGUE
               AND PCLIENTEEXT LIKE '%'||TC.CLIENTE_EXT||'%'
               AND TC.BL IS NULL
               AND TC.VIGENCIA_DEPOSITO >= trunc(SYSDATE);
        EXCEPTION 
           WHEN OTHERS THEN
             BEGIN
                SELECT CL.ID_TIPO_CONT_LINEA, 
                       CL.NOMBRE_TIPO_CONTENEDOR, 
                       TC.DEPOSITO , 
                       L.NOMBRE
                  INTO idcontlinea, 
                       tcontenedor, 
                       deposito, 
                       vlinea
                  FROM TIPO_CONT TE, 
                       TIPO_CONT_LINEA CL, 
                       TARIFAS_DEPOSITO TC, 
                       LINEAS L
                 WHERE TE.ID_TIPO_CONT = CL.ID_TIPO_CONTENEDOR
                   AND CL.ID_TIPO_CONT_LINEA = TC.ID_TIPO_CONT_LINEA
                   AND CL.LINEA = L.LINEA
                   AND TE.ID_TIPO_CONT = PTIPO_CONT
                   AND CL.LINEA = PLINEA
                   AND TC.NIT = PNITCLIENTE
                   AND TC.PUERTO_CARGUE = PPTOCARGUE
                   AND TC.PUERTO_DESCARGUE = PPTODESCARGUE
                   AND TC.CLIENTE_EXT IS NULL
                   AND TC.BL IS NULL
                   AND TC.VIGENCIA_DEPOSITO >= trunc(SYSDATE);
            EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
```

**... there are almost 30 begin exceptions nested.**

Comment: Why do you have 30 nested exceptions?  Do you really need a `when others`?  Or are you really only trying to catch a `no_data_found` exception?  Could you combine the queries into a single query with a series of `or` predicates?  Or would that result in too many rows being returned?

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, the thing that I need is return the value of a column ina register based on the combination of the values of the other columns. The parameters in the function could be NULL or not, for example the table is TARIFAS(id_client,port,container,tax) and have a register with values (100001,'CTG',NULL,'3.5') and another one with (100001,'CTG','SM09','4.2'). So I need the value of tax. If I use the OR predicate I'll have a too_many_values error when call the FUNCTION TAX(100001,'CTG','SM09'). Thanks again for the help.

Comment: I assume by "register" you mean "row".  If you're going to provide sample data, it's very helpful to edit the question so people don't have to scroll through comments.  Also tell us what the expected output is and why.  In your example, I'm not seeing why you can't have a predicate `where tbl.container = p_container or (tbl.container IS NULL AND p_container IS NULL)` to pick the one row assuming the goal is to get the row where `container` is `SM09`.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, this type of code is quite hard to debug and to mantain.

If I'm correct, the code is:

- doing many times the same query, with slightly different where conditions
- using exceptions to catch the NO_DATA_FOUND exception (it's the most probable exception when doing a select statement)

I would suggest to:

- try to aggregate many queries in one, with conditions like

  AND (TC.BL = PNUMBL OR TC.BL IS NULL)
- if this is not possible, do something like

  select count(*)
  into query1count
  from ...
  where ...conditions...

  if (query1count>0) then ...

  else

  -- do another query

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, the thing that I need is return the value of a column ina register based on the combination of the values of the other columns. The parameters in the function could be NULL or not, for example the table is TARIFAS(id_client,port,container,tax) and have a register with values (100001,'CTG',NULL,'3.5') and another one with (100001,'CTG','SM09','4.2'). So I need the value of tax. If I use the OR predicate I'll have a too_many_values error when call the FUNCTION TAX(100001,'CTG','SM09'). Thanks again for the help.